# Progress date comparision

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to make a query in Progress. I should select all records older than exactly one year, so the current date minus 1 year. I have tried several possibilities but became every time an error. The query belongs to a join and should take every record of the previous year up to the current date minus one year:

```
left outer join data.pub."vc-669" as det2  
  on deb.cddeb = det2.cddeb 
 and det2.jaar = year(curdate()) - 1 
 and det2."sys-date" < date(month(curdate()), day(curdate()), year(curdate()) - 1)
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: It is very helpful to show the actual error message that you are receiving.  Error messages are surprisingly often very helpful diagnostic tools.

Answer (score 0):

That should simply be:

```
and det2."sys-date" < add-interval( curdate(), - 1, 'year' )
```

(As this already deals with the year, there is no need to look at `det2.jaar`, too.)

https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/add-interval-function.html

Comment: I still get an error message: ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "ADD-INTERVAL(curdate(), -1, 'year' )   " (10713)

Comment: The relevant part of the query:   left outer join data.pub."aa-270" as deb  on deb.cdorg = org.cdorg
left outer join data.pub."vc-669" as det2  on deb.cddeb = det2.cddeb and det2.jaar = year(curdate()) - 1
and det2."sys-date" < ADD-INTERVAL(curdate(), -1, 'year' )
  and det2.periode <> 0

Comment: I have to look at det2.jaar because I want a summary of the data from the first day of last year up to current day minus one year to make a comaprision.